# Stored Procedure Writing

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I am new to SQL Server and I want to write a stored procedure.

I have three parameters `PAN_No`, `PolicyNo` and `ClientID` to search a details from 2 different tables with one common column `ClientID`.

`Client_details` table has columns `ClientID`, `PAN_NO`, and `Contract_Details` table has columns `ClientID`, `PolicyNo`, `DOB`.

I want to show all the details if I will search with `PAN_NO` or `PolicyNo`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.  Also, I don't see a question

Comment: -2
 
down vote 
favorite  I am new to SQL and want to make a stored procedure. I have three parameters PAN_No,PolicyNo and ClientID to search a details from 2 different table with one common Column ClientID. Client_ details table having ClientID,PAN_NO and Contract_Details table having ClientID, PolicyNo,DOB column.

I want to show all the details if i will search with PAN_NO or PolicyNo.

Comment: @user3756872: I don't think you need to repeat whole question in the comment again. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And down-votes are probably because, you haven't shown any effort to solve this!!

Comment: @user3756872: However, "develop code" given a fair piece of code in answer that you can start with!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean exactly but

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_PocedureName --give proper procedure name
    @PAN_No int, -- not sure what the exact data types
    @PolicyNo int,
    @ClientID int
AS
    SELECT 
        Column1, Column2, Column3 -- Select whatever the columns you need
    FROM
        Client_ details Client
    INNER JOIN
        Contract_Details Contract ON Contract.ClientID = Client.ClientID
    WHERE
        Client.ClientID = @ClientID 
      AND (PAN_No=@PAN_No OR PolicyNo =@PolicyNo)
```

**Update**

As a logic, you can pass a default value when not to use the parameter to search

in this case we can use 0

so

```
 SELECT
     Column1, Column2, Column3 -- Select whatever the columns you need
 FROM
     Client_ details Client
 INNER JOIN
     Contract_Details Contract ON Contract.ClientID = Client.ClientID
 WHERE
     Client.ClientID = @ClientID 
     AND (@PAN_No > 0 AND PAN_No = @PAN_No) OR 
         (@PolicyNo > 0 AND PolicyNo = @PolicyNo)
```

So this will search by @PAN_No when only the value is `>0` and same for @PolicyNo

Comment: Explain the downvote please?

Comment: can you please tell me if I want to search the details with either PAN-NO or PolicyNo...bcoz these two are in different tables and only ClientID is common column in both table.

Comment: @user3756872: Do you need to search only by one of them at a time?

Comment: ..Yes your are right..I want to search only one of them at time..thats why i am not able to conclude the query...

Comment: @user3756872: Updated the answer, please check

Comment: Thanks Develop cpde........now i am able to do the same